# VB.NET Marquee Progress Until Process Exits

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

While I have *some* VBScript experience, this is my first attempt at creating a very simple VB.NET (Windows Forms Application) wrapper for a command line application.  Please be kind!

I have a very simple GUI with two buttons that both do an action and I'd like to show a marquee progress bar until the action (read: the process) is complete (read: exits).

The 'save' button does this:

```
Dim SaveEXE As Process = Process.Start("save.exe", "/whatever /arguments")
```

From there I'm starting the marquee progress bar:

```
ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 60
ProgressBar1.Refresh()
```

I thought I could use `SaveEXE.WaitForExit()` but the Marquee starts, then stops in the middle until the process exits.  Not very useful for those watching; they'll think it hung.

I thought maybe I could do something like this but that causes my VB.Net app to crash

```
Do
    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
    ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 60
    ProgressBar1.Refresh()
Loop Until SaveEXE.ExitCode = 0
ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 60
ProgressBar1.Refresh()
```

I'm not entirely sure what needs to be done, short of getting some formal training.

Comment: Use the Exited event instead.  Assign the SynchronizingObject to make it safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new Async/Await Feature of .NET 4.5 for this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Async Sub RunProcess()
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        Dim p As Process = Process.Start("C:\test\test.exe")
        Await Task.Run(Sub() p.WaitForExit())
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RunProcess()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note the `Async` keyword in the declaration of the `RunProcess` sub and the `Await` keyword.

You run the `WaitForExit` in another thread and by using `Await` the application basically stops at this line as long as the task takes to complete.
This however also keeps your GUI reponsive meanwhile. For the example I just show the progressbar (it is invisible before) and hide it once the task is complete.

This also avoids any `Application.DoEvents` hocus pocus.

Comment: Great explanation and it fits the bill.
I modified it further to disable buttons while running and re-enable when done.  **Super simple!  Thank you kindly for the excellent - and speedy - answer!**