# Convert Await / Async in .NET 4.5 into .NET 4.0 in Visual Studio 2013 with Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013, async-await

While I have *some* scripting experience (VBscript, PowerShell, batch, shell etc.) I'm not a programmer.  I just ask that you please be kind!

**Short:**
Being very new with VB.NET, I need help re-writing Await/Async .NET 4.5 code into .NET 4.0 compatible code after including Microsoft.Bcl.Async into project.  Here's trimmed working .NET 4.5 code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Security.Principal

Private Sub buttonName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonName.Click

   // Do a bunch of stuff
   //   like assign values of text boxes to variables 
   //   validate input to a certain degree

   // Run command
   RunProcess("someexe.exe", "plenty of argments")
End Sub

Private Async Sub RunProcess(ByVal Command As String, Optional ByVal Arguments As String = "NOTSET")

   // Function to disable all the fields and buttons
    LockUI()


   // Sow the progress bar
   // Start the progress marquee so people know something's happening
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
    ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 60
    ProgressBar1.Refresh()


   // Prepare process
   Dim Execute As Process
   If Arguments = "NOTSET" Then
          Execute = Process.Start(Command)
   Else
          Execute = Process.Start(Command, Arguments)
   End If

   // Run the process and wait for it to finish
   Await Task.Run(Sub() Execute.WaitForExit())


   // Do some other stuff like check return code etc.
   // Display positive msgbox for success
   // Display failure message box for, well, failures

   // Hide progress bar since we're done
   ProgressBar1.Visible = False

   // Unlock all the fields
   UnlockUI()
End Sub
```

**Long:**
I wrote a very simple GUI wrapper for a console-only/command-line based application in Visual Studio Premium 2013.  Its really nothing more than a VB Windows Form Application with a few text boxes for user input and two buttons that perform the actions.  When either button is pressed, it executes the command with the parameters pulled from the text boxes and displays a marquee progress bar while its running, [something I needed help with recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103799/vb-net-marquee-progress-until-process-exits/26105494).

It works great, I'm thrilled and very [thankful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3055288/jens).  However, I just learned that the machines this will be used on **only have .NET 4.0**, and there won't be time to roll out .NET 4.5.  I see where I can change the Target Framework in my project, but after looking at some resources ([Link 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx), [Link 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async), [Link 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx)), I'm not sure how to re-write the code to work with Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

Comment: Does the code compile? If not, what are the errors?

Answer (score 2):

In the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package, a number of members were placed on the `TaskEx` type (since, of course, a NuGet package cannot change the `Task` type).

In your case, you can change `Task.Run` to `TaskEx.Run`.

If you want a bit more advice, `Async Sub` methods should only be used as event handlers. So it would be more proper to define `RunProcess` as returning a `Task` and have it `Await`'ed from an `Async Sub buttonName_Click`. For more information, see my [MSDN article on async best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).