# Async in VB not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, progress-bar

**UPDATE:**
It looks like the culprit is the status reporting

```
ffStatus = procFFMPEG.StandardError         'Send standard error to ffStatus
strFFout = ffStatus.ReadLine                'Read every line of output and send to strFFout
```

It look's like it breaks the async in that part. When commented out, marquee scrollbar behave as expected.

Is there a way to be able to get those data and update status while not breaking async to show marquee progressbar?

**ORIGINAL POST**

I have similar problem to this question
[VB.NET Marquee Progress Until Process Exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103799/vb-net-marquee-progress-until-process-exits)

I use the accepted answer and gets to this code

```
Public Async Sub GoConvert(theVCodec As String, theHeight As String)
    Dim theOptions As String, theApp As String, theSourcePath As String, theDestPath As String
    Dim theFilename As String, theACodec As String, theFormat As String, theLosslessOpt As String
    Dim theNewFilename As String, theNewFileTag As String, theInterlaced As String, theMsg As String
    Dim thePreset As String, theCRF As String

    Dim ffStatus As StreamReader, strFFout As String

    'On Error GoTo Handler
    'SET DEFAULT VALUES

    theApp = "ffmpeg.exe"
    theSourcePath = txtSource.Text
    theDestPath = txtOutput.Text & "\"
    theACodec = "libmp3lame"
    thePreset = "veryfast"
    theCRF = "22"

    theInterlaced = ""
    theNewFileTag = ""
    theLosslessOpt = ""

    Select Case theVCodec
        Case "libx264"
            theNewFileTag = "x264"
        Case "libxvid"
            theNewFileTag = "xvid"
        Case "libx265"
            theNewFileTag = "x265"
    End Select

    If cmbUseCodec.Text = "x264 vegas" Then
        theACodec = "aac"
        theNewFileTag = "x264forVegas"
    End If

    theMsg = "IF FILE EXISTS, IT WILL BE OVERWRITTEN!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please make sure that there is no filename conflict in the destination folder," & vbCrLf & "Encoder will overwrite existing files." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to continue?"

    If MessageBox.Show(theMsg, "WARNING!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) = DialogResult.Yes Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To lstSourceFiles.Items.Count - 1

            If chkToFileType.CheckedItems.Count <> 0 Then
                Dim x As Integer
                Dim forVegas As String

                For x = 0 To chkToFileType.CheckedItems.Count - 1

                    theFormat = chkToFileType.CheckedItems(x).ToString

                    'GET FILENAMES ON FILES LISTBOX
                    theFilename = lstSourceFiles.Items(i).ToString
                    theNewFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(theFilename)

                    If chkSameOutputFolder.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
                        theDestPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(theFilename) & "\"
                    End If

                    If (theVCodec = "libx265") Then
                        theCRF = "28"
                        thePreset = "medium"
                    End If
                    If (chkLossLess.CheckedItems.Count > 0) And (theVCodec = "libx265") Then
                        theLosslessOpt = "-x265-params lossless=1 "
                    End If


                    If theFormat = "mp3" Then
                        '-i "%%a" -qa 0 - map a "%%~na.mp3"
                        theOptions = " -i " & Chr(34) & theFilename & Chr(34) & " -y -q:a 0 -map a " & Chr(34) & theDestPath & theNewFilename & "." & theFormat & Chr(34)
                    Else
                        'PREPARE NEW FILENAME OF CONVERTED FILE
                        theNewFilename = theNewFilename & "-" & theNewFileTag & "-" & theHeight & "p"

                        theOptions = " -i " & Chr(34) & theFilename & Chr(34) & " -y -vcodec " & theVCodec
                        theOptions = theOptions & " -vf " & theInterlaced & "scale=" & Chr(34) & "trunc(oh*a/2)*2:" & theHeight & Chr(34)

                        If cmbUseCodec.Text = "x264 vegas" Then
                            forVegas = " -strict experimental -tune fastdecode -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:a 192k -ar 48000"
                            theOptions = theOptions & " -preset " & thePreset & " -crf " & theCRF & " -acodec " & theACodec & forVegas
                            theOptions = theOptions & " -threads 4 " & theLosslessOpt & Chr(34) & theDestPath & theNewFilename & "." & theFormat & Chr(34)
                        Else
                            theOptions = theOptions & " -b 1750k -preset " & thePreset & " -crf " & theCRF & " -acodec " & theACodec
                            theOptions = theOptions & " -ac 2 -ab 160k -threads 4 " & theLosslessOpt & Chr(34) & theDestPath & theNewFilename & "." & theFormat & Chr(34)
                        End If
                    End If
                    theOptions = theOptions & " -loglevel error -stats"


                    'LET'S GET READY TO CONVERT
                    ConvertProcessInfo.FileName = theApp
                    ConvertProcessInfo.Arguments = theOptions

                    'LET'S TRY TO CAPTURE STATUS
                    ConvertProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
                    ConvertProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
                    ConvertProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                    ConvertProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

                    'LET'S PROVIDE SOME MEANINGFUL INFO
                    procFFMPEG.StartInfo = ConvertProcessInfo
                    lstStatus.Items(i) = "Encoding: " & theFormat
                    txtProcessInfo.Text = "Encoding file: " & theNewFilename & "." & theFormat

                    'LET'S DISABLE CONTROLS WHILE CONVERT IS WORKING AND ENABLE PROGRESSBAR
                    prgrssConvert.Visible = True
                    DisableControls()

                    'LET'S CONVERT
                    procFFMPEG.Start()

                    Do
                        Application.DoEvents()
                        ffStatus = procFFMPEG.StandardError         'Send standard error to ffStatus
                        strFFout = ffStatus.ReadLine                'Read every line of output and send to strFFout
                        Debug.Print(strFFout)
                        txtProcessInfo.Text = strFFout

                        'THESE LINES IS NOT NEEDED IF ASYNC WILL WORK
                        txtProcessInfo.Refresh()
                        lstSourceFiles.Refresh()
                        lstStatus.Refresh()
                        prgrssConvert.Refresh()

                    Loop Until procFFMPEG.HasExited

                    'LET'S WAIT FOR PROCESS TO EXIT
                    Await Task.Run(Sub() procFFMPEG.WaitForExit())

                    'UPDATE STATUS AFTER EVERY FILE
                    prgrssConvert.Visible = False
                    lstStatus.Items(i) = "DONE"
                Next
            End If
        Next
        'WHEN ALL FILES DONE, UPDATE STATUS
        txtProcessInfo.Text = "Encoding completed. Waiting for new task"
        EnableControls()
    End If

End Sub
```

My problem is that the progressbar *(prgrssConvert.Visible = True)* is not updating asynchronously that is why I have to add refresh in the DO LOOP but it is not that visually appealing because it is "robotic" and not smoothly flowing marquee.

It looks to me that async is not doing it's job. I am hoping to keep the progressbar marquee running while waiting for the ffmpeg process to complete.

Any idea why async is not working on my code?

Thanks

Comment: Do **NOT** ever use `Application.DoEvents()`. It can cause all sorts of issues with code and can be very hard to debug. And using it in a loop is just compounding the issue. You need to use a timer to get the result you want.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity can you elaborate on the timer? Application.DoEvents() was used out of frustration :) removing it does not change a thing.

Comment: StandardError.ReadLine() is a blocking call.  That can take a long time if you do it right, hopefully the process doesn't generate a lot of error messages.  That hangs your UI thread and stops the progress bar from updating.  Either use BeginReadLine() or move this code into a worker thread.  And fix the other bug, you are not reading StandardOutput.  That can cause the program to hang forever.

Comment: Your problem is you are trying to get a progress on your encoding but you need a function that would return the progress on an async call.

Comment: If you want a progress bar without having an async function to update your progress bar then use the progress bar to show progress on your file list to encode instead.

Comment: where is procFFMPEG declared. I don't seem to find it in your sub. Is it global? and why if it is?

Comment: I figured out exactly what your issue is. You are thinking that running the process in the background like you are doing is async. It's not.. when running ffmpeg.exe inside a process class let you run the process on a different thread. You are only encoding one file at the time and I don't think your app is complex enough that while it's encoding, you can setup a new batch to encode when this one finish. You aren't doing anything worth setting all that up to work. Just remove everything in your do Loop and keep your doevents() and your loop condition. Make your progress bar for each file.

Comment: @Chillzy I do not need to return the progress on anything. I simple want the progressbar control with style marquee (infinite progress) to display curently, when the process starts, the window is frozen. the marquee is not running.

Comment: @Wayne do you need to read the error output for errors or that was just for debugging?

Comment: Yes i do because this is my current progress. it reports the current frame and current time of ffmpeg convert. the problem is the marquee progress bar gets frozen while inside the loop

Comment: @Wayne Did you try the code I posted? Or maybe the second answer from a different user? You are trying to read a line from the error output and until there's CrLF sent at the end of the line your app will be stuck there. When using ReadLineAsync it will return nothing if nothing to read otherwise will return the next full line available. You should also be reading the standardOutput instead of standardError?. You can also look this NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/EmergenceGuardian.FFmpeg/  It's a wrapper for ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There perfect answer for a good questions. I didn't see you were returning the output to a textbox. sorry. You have to use readlineasync otherwise your are waiting for a line from your output that might only come at the end. If it never comes your app will be stuck there.

This is for reading errors procFFMPEG.StandardError
If you actually want the output of your process use this
procMMFPEG.StandardOutput instead or both but you will need to adapt your code to it

[some reference for StandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Public Async Sub GoConvert(theVCodec As String, theHeight As String)
    Dim theOptions As String, theApp As String, theSourcePath As String, theDestPath As String
    Dim theFilename As String, theACodec As String, theFormat As String, theLosslessOpt As String
    Dim theNewFilename As String, theNewFileTag As String, theInterlaced As String, theMsg As String
    Dim thePreset As String, theCRF As String

    Dim ffStatus As StreamReader, strFFout As String

    'On Error GoTo Handler
    'SET DEFAULT VALUES

    theApp = "ffmpeg.exe"
    theSourcePath = txtSource.Text
    theDestPath = txtOutput.Text & "\"
    theACodec = "libmp3lame"
    thePreset = "veryfast"
    theCRF = "22"

    theInterlaced = ""
    theNewFileTag = ""
    theLosslessOpt = ""

    Select Case theVCodec
        Case "libx264"
            theNewFileTag = "x264"
        Case "libxvid"
            theNewFileTag = "xvid"
        Case "libx265"
            theNewFileTag = "x265"
    End Select

    If cmbUseCodec.Text = "x264 vegas" Then
        theACodec = "aac"
        theNewFileTag = "x264forVegas"
    End If

    theMsg = "IF FILE EXISTS, IT WILL BE OVERWRITTEN!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please make sure that there is no filename conflict in the destination folder," & vbCrLf & "Encoder will overwrite existing files." _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to continue?"

    If MessageBox.Show(theMsg, "WARNING!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        'LET'S DISABLE CONTROLS WHILE CONVERT IS WORKING AND ENABLE PROGRESSBAR
        prgrssConvert.Visible = True
        DisableControls()
        prgrssConvert.value = 0 'I assumed this was a progressbar
        prgrssConvert.maximum = lstSourceFiles.Items.Count * chkToFileType.CheckedItems.Count

        For i As Integer = 0 To lstSourceFiles.Items.Count - 1

            If chkToFileType.CheckedItems.Count <> 0 Then
                Dim x As Integer
                Dim forVegas As String

                For x = 0 To chkToFileType.CheckedItems.Count - 1

                    theFormat = chkToFileType.CheckedItems(x).ToString

                    'GET FILENAMES ON FILES LISTBOX
                    theFilename = lstSourceFiles.Items(i).ToString
                    theNewFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(theFilename)

                    If chkSameOutputFolder.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
                        theDestPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(theFilename) & "\"
                    End If

                    If (theVCodec = "libx265") Then
                        theCRF = "28"
                        thePreset = "medium"
                    End If
                    If (chkLossLess.CheckedItems.Count > 0) And (theVCodec = "libx265") Then
                        theLosslessOpt = "-x265-params lossless=1 "
                    End If


                    If theFormat = "mp3" Then
                        '-i "%%a" -qa 0 - map a "%%~na.mp3"
                        theOptions = " -i " & Chr(34) & theFilename & Chr(34) & " -y -q:a 0 -map a " & Chr(34) & theDestPath & theNewFilename & "." & theFormat & Chr(34)
                    Else
                        'PREPARE NEW FILENAME OF CONVERTED FILE
                        theNewFilename = theNewFilename & "-" & theNewFileTag & "-" & theHeight & "p"

                        theOptions = " -i " & Chr(34) & theFilename & Chr(34) & " -y -vcodec " & theVCodec
                        theOptions = theOptions & " -vf " & theInterlaced & "scale=" & Chr(34) & "trunc(oh*a/2)*2:" & theHeight & Chr(34)

                        If cmbUseCodec.Text = "x264 vegas" Then
                            forVegas = " -strict experimental -tune fastdecode -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:a 192k -ar 48000"
                            theOptions = theOptions & " -preset " & thePreset & " -crf " & theCRF & " -acodec " & theACodec & forVegas
                            theOptions = theOptions & " -threads 4 " & theLosslessOpt & Chr(34) & theDestPath & theNewFilename & "." & theFormat & Chr(34)
                        Else
                            theOptions = theOptions & " -b 1750k -preset " & thePreset & " -crf " & theCRF & " -acodec " & theACodec
                            theOptions = theOptions & " -ac 2 -ab 160k -threads 4 " & theLosslessOpt & Chr(34) & theDestPath & theNewFilename & "." & theFormat & Chr(34)
                        End If
                    End If
                    theOptions = theOptions & " -loglevel error -stats"


                    'LET'S GET READY TO CONVERT
                    ConvertProcessInfo.FileName = theApp
                    ConvertProcessInfo.Arguments = theOptions

                    'LET'S TRY TO CAPTURE STATUS
                    ConvertProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
                    ConvertProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
                    ConvertProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                    ConvertProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

                    'LET'S PROVIDE SOME MEANINGFUL INFO
                    procFFMPEG.StartInfo = ConvertProcessInfo
                    lstStatus.Items(i) = "Encoding: " & theFormat
                    txtProcessInfo.Text = "Encoding file: " & theNewFilename & "." & theFormat


                    'LET'S CONVERT
                    procFFMPEG.Start()
                    Do
                        ffStatus = procFFMPEG.StandardError         'Send standard error to ffStatus
                        strFFout = Await(ffStatus.ReadLineAsync())               'Read every line of output and send to strFFout
                        Debug.Print(strFFout)
                        txtProcessInfo.Text = strFFout
                    Loop Until procFFMPEG.HasExited = True



                    'UPDATE STATUS AFTER EVERY FILE
                    prgrssConvert.value += 1
                Next
                lstStatus.Items(i) = "DONE"
            End If
        Next
        prgrssConvert.Visible = False

        'WHEN ALL FILES DONE, UPDATE STATUS
        txtProcessInfo.Text = "Encoding completed. Waiting for new task"
        EnableControls()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: For the sake of those who will look at this answer in the future, to save your time looking for what fix the problem is this line. **strFFout = Await(ffStatus.ReadLineAsync())**

Answer (score -1):

This is untested, but can you try this:

```
                Do
                    Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
                    ffStatus = procFFMPEG.StandardError         'Send standard error to ffStatus
                    strFFout = ffStatus.ReadLine                'Read every line of output and send to strFFout
                    Debug.Print(strFFout)
                    txtProcessInfo.Text = strFFout

                Loop Until Await Task.Run(Function() procFFMPEG.HasExited)
```

---

Here's a simple bit of code to test that this works:

```
Dim process As New Process()

process.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe")
process.Start()

Do
    Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
    Console.WriteLine("!")
Loop Until Await Task.Run(Function() process.HasExited)
```

It produces lines of `!` until the PowerShell console is closed.

Comment: Same result. Progressbar updates only within the loop causing it to behave like a timer that updates every loop instead of running marquee smoothly

Comment: please check my comments on the original post. The do while event is working fine. What I do not like is the way it animate. its like a tic tac tic tac animation not smooth scroll. currently I have a textbox that update the current convert progress by showing current time and frames. this is fine for now. the problem is the marquee progress bar is frozen during the loop. thanks

Comment: @Wayne. The line with readline() is the line blocking. Did you try the answer I provided?